# Как вывести результаты двух функций в один textbox?

Tags: c#

Представляю текст из textbox4 в двоичном виде:

```
string Encrypt() //random to binary
    {
        var encrypt = textBox4.Text;

        StringBuilder binary = new StringBuilder();           
        for (int i = 0; i < encrypt.Length; i++)
        {
            binary.Append(Convert.ToString(encrypt[i], 2).PadLeft(8, '0'));
        }
        return binary.ToString();     
    }
```

Делаю одно и то же, но с текстом, который находится в textbox1

```
public string bina()
    {
        var ToBinary = textBox1.Text;
        StringBuilder binary = new StringBuilder();

        for (int i = 0; i < ToBinary.Length; i++)
        {
            binary.Append(Convert.ToString(ToBinary[i], 2).PadLeft(8, '0'));
        }
        return binary.ToString();
    }
```

А здесь я пытаюсь вызвать две функции:

```
private void carbonFiberButton11_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {             
        textBox1.Text = Encrypt();
        textBox1.Text = bina();    
    }
```

Идея такая: я ввожу любой текст в textbox1, а затем нажимаю на "carbonFiberButton11_Click_1". Текст, введенный в textbox1 переводится в двоичный вид и к нему добавляется уже закодированный текст из textbox4. 
Но происходит следующее - в textbox1 выводится результат "string Encrypt()", а текст, который был введен заранее, просто пропадает.

Я это проверил так:

```
string teeeexx = textBox1.Text;
            string temp = null;
            if (teeeexx.Length % 8 != 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Кол-во цифр не кратно 8");
                return;
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < teeeexx.Length; i += 8)
            {
                temp += (char)Convert.ToByte(teeeexx.Substring(i, 8), 2);
            }
            textBox1.Text = temp;
```

Переведя из binary в string, я вижу текст, который я вводил в textbox4. 
А мне нужно просто вывести два результата в textbox1. help

Comment: Если я правильно вас понял, то попробуйте следующее: в обработчике события кнопки - `textBox1.Text = Encrypt(); textBox1.Text += bina();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Всё очень просто, вместо того, что бы вывести первую и вторую строку вы по очереди их присваиваете, и новое присвоение, что логично, убирает всё что было написано до этого.
Просто вместо **" = "**

```
textBox1.Text = Encrypt();
textBox1.Text = bina();
```

следует писать **" += "**

```
textBox1.Text += Encrypt();
textBox1.Text += bina();
```

тогда новая строка будет добавляться в конец старой.